# How to change the grub default kernel to temporarily boot with specified kernel in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, command-line, server, grub2, kernel

I am new to Linux.

We have a Linux server and we have only CLI access. We need to change the kernel for some specific reason.  Suppose that the server has an old kernel and a new kernel available. We know that old kernel can boot your system correctly and you want to test new kernel.

How to test this without crashing the server? I have read many articles and don't understand any of them.

https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/legacy/Booting-once_002donly.html
https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/legacy/Booting-fallback-systems.html

Comment: You've provided few specifics; Ubuntu 20.04 LTS was a LTS release thus has a choice of kernel stacks, but you've given no specifics as to which you're using, and what you're trying to revert to. Switching stacks maybe a better option than using an *unpatched* kernel, especially if the change you're having relates to the recent kernel stack change - but you weren't specific with details on what you're using. I suggest you be specific.

Comment: hey we are installing a azure migrate agent in our costumer environment and their are specific kernel version this agent supports below is the link for the supported kernel and the costumer has 5.04.0-128-generic  and we are trying to upgrade to 5.04.0-121-generic  or 5.04.0-122-generic  but we dont know this is a stable kernel or not so their is a option to try newer kernel called Booting once-only but i am not able to setup             .